Problem when using YOLOv8 with NCNN on Raspberry Pi 4

I'm using this c++ program on raspberry pi 4: https://github.com/Qengineering/YoloV8-ncnn-Raspberry-Pi-4 , when using the standard yolov8n.bin and yolov8.param weights that you can find in the repo, it works fine and swiftly, but when I try to change the code and use my personally trained model, it doesn't work and stops with a segmentation fault.
I've tried multiple methods to get the ncnn model:

The python yolov8 method:

from ultralytics import YOLO
import ncnn

model=YOLO('yolov8n.pt')

model.train(data="data.yaml", epochs=100, batch=8)  
path = model.export(format="ncnn")


Converting from onnx to ncnn

from ultralytics import YOLO

model=YOLO('yolov8n.pt')

model.train(data="data.yaml", epochs=100, batch=8)  
path = model.export(format="onxx")

After running this code, I've followed the steps in this guide: https://github.com/Tencent/ncnn/wiki/use-ncnn-with-pytorch-or-onnx
These two methods create two different model.param file, but none of them work. I've tried using these files to predict with YOLOv8 in Python, and the model works in Python, but stop working with the C++ code.
I've tried to locate the point where the segmentation fault happens, but it's too deep in the code for me to understand it.
If someone can help i'll be grateful because this is driving me crazy
The C++ code is running with OpenCV 4.9.0 compiled.
This is the modified c++ source code:
yolov8.cpp
#include "yoloV8.h"

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

const char* class_names[] = {
    "ambulance"
};

static float fast_exp(float x)
{
    union {
        uint32_t i;
        float f;
    } v{};
    v.i = (1 << 23) * (1.4426950409 * x + 126.93490512f);
    return v.f;
}

static float sigmoid(float x)
{
    return 1.0f / (1.0f + fast_exp(-x));
}
static float intersection_area(const Object& a, const Object& b)
{
    cv::Rect_<float> inter = a.rect & b.rect;
    return inter.area();
}

static void qsort_descent_inplace(std::vector<Object>& faceobjects, int left, int right)
{
    int i = left;
    int j = right;
    float p = faceobjects[(left + right) / 2].prob;

    while (i <= j)
    {
        while (faceobjects[i].prob > p)
            i++;

        while (faceobjects[j].prob < p)
            j--;

        if (i <= j)
        {
            // swap
            std::swap(faceobjects[i], faceobjects[j]);

            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }

    //     #pragma omp parallel sections
    {
        //         #pragma omp section
        {
            if (left < j) qsort_descent_inplace(faceobjects, left, j);
        }
        //         #pragma omp section
        {
            if (i < right) qsort_descent_inplace(faceobjects, i, right);
        }
    }
}

static void qsort_descent_inplace(std::vector<Object>& faceobjects)
{
    if (faceobjects.empty())
        return;

    qsort_descent_inplace(faceobjects, 0, faceobjects.size() - 1);
}

static void nms_sorted_bboxes(const std::vector<Object>& faceobjects, std::vector<int>& picked, float nms_threshold)
{
    picked.clear();

    const int n = faceobjects.size();

    std::vector<float> areas(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        areas[i] = faceobjects[i].rect.width * faceobjects[i].rect.height;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        const Object& a = faceobjects[i];

        int keep = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < (int)picked.size(); j++)
        {
            const Object& b = faceobjects[picked[j]];

            // intersection over union
            float inter_area = intersection_area(a, b);
            float union_area = areas[i] + areas[picked[j]] - inter_area;
            // float IoU = inter_area / union_area
            if (inter_area / union_area > nms_threshold)
                keep = 0;
        }

        if (keep)
            picked.push_back(i);
    }
}
static void generate_grids_and_stride(const int target_w, const int target_h, std::vector<int>& strides, std::vector<GridAndStride>& grid_strides)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)strides.size(); i++)
    {
        int stride = strides[i];
        int num_grid_w = target_w / stride;
        int num_grid_h = target_h / stride;
        for (int g1 = 0; g1 < num_grid_h; g1++)
        {
            for (int g0 = 0; g0 < num_grid_w; g0++)
            {
                GridAndStride gs;
                gs.grid0 = g0;
                gs.grid1 = g1;
                gs.stride = stride;
                grid_strides.push_back(gs);
            }
        }
    }
}
static void generate_proposals(std::vector<GridAndStride> grid_strides, const ncnn::Mat& pred, float prob_threshold, std::vector<Object>& objects)
{
    const int num_points = grid_strides.size();
    const int num_class = 1;
    const int reg_max_1 = 16;

    for (int i = 0; i < num_points; i++)
    {
        const float* scores = pred.row(i) + 4 * reg_max_1;

        // find label with max score
        int label = -1;
        float score = -FLT_MAX;
        for (int k = 0; k < num_class; k++)
        {
            float confidence = scores[k];
            if (confidence > score)
            {
                label = k;
                score = confidence;
            }
        }
        float box_prob = sigmoid(score);
        if (box_prob >= prob_threshold)
        {
            ncnn::Mat bbox_pred(reg_max_1, 4, (void*)pred.row(i));
            {
                ncnn::Layer* softmax = ncnn::create_layer("Softmax");

                ncnn::ParamDict pd;
                pd.set(0, 1); // axis
                pd.set(1, 1);
                softmax->load_param(pd);

                ncnn::Option opt;
                opt.num_threads = 1;
                opt.use_packing_layout = false;

                softmax->create_pipeline(opt);

                softmax->forward_inplace(bbox_pred, opt);

                softmax->destroy_pipeline(opt);

                delete softmax;
            }

            float pred_ltrb[4];
            for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
            {
                float dis = 0.f;
                const float* dis_after_sm = bbox_pred.row(k);
                for (int l = 0; l < reg_max_1; l++)
                {
                    dis += l * dis_after_sm[l];
                }

                pred_ltrb[k] = dis * grid_strides[i].stride;
            }

            float pb_cx = (grid_strides[i].grid0 + 0.5f) * grid_strides[i].stride;
            float pb_cy = (grid_strides[i].grid1 + 0.5f) * grid_strides[i].stride;

            float x0 = pb_cx - pred_ltrb[0];
            float y0 = pb_cy - pred_ltrb[1];
            float x1 = pb_cx + pred_ltrb[2];
            float y1 = pb_cy + pred_ltrb[3];

            Object obj;
            obj.rect.x = x0;
            obj.rect.y = y0;
            obj.rect.width = x1 - x0;
            obj.rect.height = y1 - y0;
            obj.label = label;
            obj.prob = box_prob;

            objects.push_back(obj);
        }
    }
}

YoloV8::YoloV8()
{
}


int YoloV8::load(int _target_size)
{
    yolo.clear();

    yolo.opt = ncnn::Option();

    yolo.opt.num_threads = 4;

    yolo.load_param("./best.param");
    yolo.load_model("./best.bin");

    target_size = _target_size;
    mean_vals[0] = 103.53f;
    mean_vals[1] = 116.28f;
    mean_vals[2] = 123.675f;
    norm_vals[0] = 1.0 / 255.0f;
    norm_vals[1] = 1.0 / 255.0f;
    norm_vals[2] = 1.0 / 255.0f;

    return 0;
}

int YoloV8::detect(const cv::Mat& rgb, std::vector<Object>& objects, float prob_threshold, float nms_threshold)
{
    int width = rgb.cols;
    int height = rgb.rows;

    // pad to multiple of 32
    int w = width;
    int h = height;
    float scale = 1.f;
    if (w > h)
    {
        scale = (float)target_size / w;
        w = target_size;
        h = h * scale;
    }
    else
    {
        scale = (float)target_size / h;
        h = target_size;
        w = w * scale;
    }

    ncnn::Mat in = ncnn::Mat::from_pixels_resize(rgb.data, ncnn::Mat::PIXEL_RGB2BGR, width, height, w, h);

    // pad to target_size rectangle
    int wpad = (w + 31) / 32 * 32 - w;
    int hpad = (h + 31) / 32 * 32 - h;
    ncnn::Mat in_pad;
    ncnn::copy_make_border(in, in_pad, hpad / 2, hpad - hpad / 2, wpad / 2, wpad - wpad / 2, ncnn::BORDER_CONSTANT, 0.f);

    in_pad.substract_mean_normalize(0, norm_vals);

    ncnn::Extractor ex = yolo.create_extractor();

    ex.input("images", in_pad);

    std::vector<Object> proposals;

    ncnn::Mat out;
    ex.extract("output0", out);

    std::vector<int> strides = {8, 16, 32}; // might have stride=64
    std::vector<GridAndStride> grid_strides;
    generate_grids_and_stride(in_pad.w, in_pad.h, strides, grid_strides);
    generate_proposals(grid_strides, out, prob_threshold, proposals);

    // sort all proposals by score from highest to lowest
    qsort_descent_inplace(proposals);

    // apply nms with nms_threshold
    std::vector<int> picked;
    nms_sorted_bboxes(proposals, picked, nms_threshold);

    int count = picked.size();

    objects.resize(count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        objects[i] = proposals[picked[i]];

        // adjust offset to original unpadded
        float x0 = (objects[i].rect.x - (wpad / 2)) / scale;
        float y0 = (objects[i].rect.y - (hpad / 2)) / scale;
        float x1 = (objects[i].rect.x + objects[i].rect.width - (wpad / 2)) / scale;
        float y1 = (objects[i].rect.y + objects[i].rect.height - (hpad / 2)) / scale;

        // clip
        x0 = std::max(std::min(x0, (float)(width - 1)), 0.f);
        y0 = std::max(std::min(y0, (float)(height - 1)), 0.f);
        x1 = std::max(std::min(x1, (float)(width - 1)), 0.f);
        y1 = std::max(std::min(y1, (float)(height - 1)), 0.f);

        objects[i].rect.x = x0;
        objects[i].rect.y = y0;
        objects[i].rect.width = x1 - x0;
        objects[i].rect.height = y1 - y0;
    }

    // sort objects by area
    struct
    {
        bool operator()(const Object& a, const Object& b) const
        {
            return a.rect.area() > b.rect.area();
        }
    } objects_area_greater;
    std::sort(objects.begin(), objects.end(), objects_area_greater);

    return 0;
}

int YoloV8::draw(cv::Mat& rgb, const std::vector<Object>& objects)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++)
    {
        const Object& obj = objects[i];

//         fprintf(stderr, "%d = %.5f at %.2f %.2f %.2f x %.2f\n", obj.label, obj.prob,
//                 obj.rect.x, obj.rect.y, obj.rect.width, obj.rect.height);

        cv::rectangle(rgb, obj.rect, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0));

        char text[256];
        sprintf(text, "%s %.1f%%", class_names[obj.label], obj.prob * 100);

        int baseLine = 0;
        cv::Size label_size = cv::getTextSize(text, cv::FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, 1, &baseLine);

        int x = obj.rect.x;
        int y = obj.rect.y - label_size.height - baseLine;
        if (y < 0)
            y = 0;
        if (x + label_size.width > rgb.cols)
            x = rgb.cols - label_size.width;

        cv::rectangle(rgb, cv::Rect(cv::Point(x, y), cv::Size(label_size.width, label_size.height + baseLine)),
                      cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255), -1);

        cv::putText(rgb, text, cv::Point(x, y + label_size.height),
                    cv::FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0));
    }

    return 0;
}

yolov8main.cpp
#include "yoloV8.h"

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

YoloV8 yolov8;
int target_size = 640; //416; //320;  must be divisible by 32.

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const char* imagepath = argv[1];

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [imagepath]\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    cv::Mat m = cv::imread(imagepath, 1);
    if (m.empty())
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "cv::imread %s failed\n", imagepath);
        return -1;
    }

    yolov8.load(target_size);       //load model (once) see yoloyV8.cpp line 246

    std::vector<Object> objects;
    yolov8.detect(m, objects);      //recognize the objects
    yolov8.draw(m, objects);        //show the outcome

    cv::imshow("RPi4 - 1.95 GHz - 2 GB ram",m);
//    cv::imwrite("out.jpg",m);
    cv::waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}

yolov8.h

#ifndef YOLOV8_H
#define YOLOV8_H

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <net.h>

struct Object
{
    cv::Rect_<float> rect;
    int label;
    float prob;
};

struct GridAndStride
{
    int grid0;
    int grid1;
    int stride;
};

class YoloV8
{
public:
    YoloV8();
    int load(int target_size);
    int detect(const cv::Mat& rgb, std::vector<Object>& objects, float prob_threshold = 0.4f, float nms_threshold = 0.5f);
    int draw(cv::Mat& rgb, const std::vector<Object>& objects);
private:
    ncnn::Net yolo;
    int target_size;
    float mean_vals[3];
    float norm_vals[3];
};

#endif // YOLOV8_H


Can the error be reproduced with the official yolov8 model? If so, please mark that as part of your [mre]. If not you need to add actual debugging information.

Can u be more specific what do u mean with "actual debugging information" ? I'm asking because this is my first post, if u can explain i'll be glad to add it to the post

If this can help even if i export the standard yolov8n.pt file to ncnn the param file is different from the one in the repo

Hi there - your question needs more relevant details. What did you change? What error did you get? Please read how to ask for more information about asking good questions on StackOverflow. So far you've told us "I changed something and it broke". The easy answer is to say "So change it back." Knowing nothing about this code, does the data in your custom trained model look right? Is it about the same size as the default model?

I've seen the yolov8.cpp code you provided used in the nanodet ncnn android app. I also tried similar process as yours but no success. I'm not really sure if that code make sense for yolo models.
Here is an accurate tested flow for the exported yolov8 model in a c++ app:

Use the letterbox function provided by ultralytics to add padding to the input, the function can be found in their c++ examples.
Use ncnn to load the model, pay attentions to the names of the output and input layers (out0, in0).
In the current ultralytics repository version, the output of the model should be
of the shape (batch(1), coords (4) + num_classes(80),
number_of_detections (8400)), the batch_size is always 1.
Store the output in a cv.Mat this can be achieved using the
constructor
Transpose the output dimensions (dim(1)<->dim(2))
Loop over the model detections (8400) and store them in a vector
Use cv::nms function to remove redundant boxes

This flow works for ncnn, tflite and onnx.
